# Visual Studio - Affect all textboxes at once

Tags: vb.net, textbox, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to remove leading zeroes from my textboxes. I have the code working, but I have close to 50 textboxes. I don't really want to have to make 50 `textbox.TextChanged` events.

Is there anyway to affect all of the textboxes with the same code?

This is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub txtTier1_100_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTier1_100.TextChanged

    txtTier1_100.Text = txtTier1_100.Text.TrimStart("0"c)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to define a general purpose handler

```
Private Sub HandleTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
  Dim tb = CType(sender, TextBox)
  tb.Text = tb.Text.TrimStart("0"c)
End Sub
```

Then attach every one of your `TextBox` instances to this single handler

```
AddHandler txtTier1_100.TextChanged, AddressOf HandleTextChanged
AddHandler txtTier1_101.TextChanged, AddressOf HandleTextChanged
AddHandler txtTier1_102.TextChanged, AddressOf HandleTextChanged
```

Note that if you had all of the `TextBox` instances in a collection this could be done with a `For Each` loop as well

```
ForEach tb in textBoxList 
  AddHandler tb.TextChanged, AddressOf HandleTextChanged
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! I put the AddHandlers in the Form_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub txtTier1_100_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTier1_100.TextChanged, txtTier1_101.TextChanged, txtTier1_102.TextChanged...

        'sender is the right textbox

    End Sub
```