# I do not know why I am getting this 'Addressof' error?

Tags: vb.net

I got a problem when using this add handler. It keeps on saying

> "AddressOf operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)".

I am not sure what I have done wrong for this to occur.
The code for the add handler:

`AddHandler NudQuantityOfItem(a).SelectedItem, AddressOf TotalPrice(T)`

The code for the `Totalprice`:

```
`Public Sub Totalprice(ByVal a As Integer)
    For T = 1 To CInt(CustomerMenu.NudQuantityOfItem.SelectedItem)
        TotalItemPriceCalculation(T, a)
    Next
End Sub`
```

The code for the `Quantity`:

```
    NudQuantityOfItem(a) = New numericupdowncounter
    NudQuantityOfItem(a).Location = New Point(X, Y)
    NudQuantityofitem(a).Width = 23 :       cboQuantity(i).Height = 33`
```

Comment: It should be `AddressOf StarterQuantityPrice` (without the parameter). Just like the message says... You'll have to find another way to get that parameter in there. The usual way is through `sender As Object`.

Comment: The way you wrote it, StarterQuantityPrice(i) would have to be a function that returns a delegate.

Comment: Check this answer for a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21420015/1220550

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand???

Comment: Stop removing your code from the question.  It helped answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive of this but I think the target of teh AddressOf needs the same signature as hooked event.

e.g.

```
AddHandler c.TextChanged, AddressOf SetDirty

Private Sub SetDirty(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not mbDirty AndAlso Not mbFormLoad Then
        mbDirty = True
      ....
End Sub
```

Note that SetDirty as the same parameters as does TextChanged.

In your case you would use Sender to defined the control that changed and then find the required value.